# How to make click to call in Ionic For IOS?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I have tried this method and it is working perfevtly in Android but not in IOS

```
<a href="tel: 1111111">Call</a>
```

And in my config.xml file

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

the above method is tested in real devices and it is working only for android, is there any other method to make it work in IOS

Answer (score 2):

This method worked for me in IOS

```
<div onclick="window.open('tel:7795713372', '_system', 'location=yes')">Call me</div>
```

Also you need to install [cordova inapp browser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) plugin. And need to [whitelist](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) the request in config.xml by adding [whitelist](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to make it work

```
<a href="tel:number" class="button button-positive">Call me</a>
```

Comment: @Prathik Kotian: If you find my answer working & helpful. Kindly accept the answer :)

Comment: You can also try <a class="button icon-left ion-ios7-telephone button-calm button-outline" ng-href="tel: {{phoneno}}">Call (number)</a>

Comment: There is no difference between my method and your answer, just the css class has been changed. and yes , I have tried too

Comment: @PrathikKotian Have you tried the last comment I posted?

Comment: @iYound yes i did, and the result was the same

Answer (score 1):

For your code to work on IOS you need to add in the config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
```

Doing this breaks the functionality on android so make sure to add it inside

```
<platform name="ios">
```

Answer (score 0):

To work on IOS you need to add in the config.xml

in .js
window.open('tel:' + number, '_system');